Is always $KL[f(x|a) || g(x|a) ] \leq KL[f(x) || g(x) ]$ for fixed $a$?
Suppose we have two prior distributions over $X$, namely $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (assume $X$ is finite if necessary). Define $f(x|a) = Z_f\cdot f(x)\cdot h(a|x)$ and $g(x|a) = Z_g \cdot g(x) \cdot h(a|x)$, where $Z_f$ and $Z_g$ are normalization constants. Then for a fixed $a$, define $f_a(x) = f(x|a)$ and $g_a(x)=g(x|a)$.
Is it then always the case for any $a$ that $KL[f_a(x) || g_a(x) ] \leq KL[f(x) || g(x) ]$?
I am not sure how to prove it. Conceptually it reminds me of the data processing inequality, but the latter is about mutual information.
If not, can we at least bound $KL[f_a(x) || g_a(x) ] $ in terms of $KL[f(x) || g(x) ]$ somehow?

No.  If you define distributions so that $f(x|a=0)$, $g(x|a=0)$ are very different from each other but $f(x|a=1)=g(x|a=1)$, then you should easily be able to construct a counterexample where $KL[f_a(x) || g_a(x) ]$ is large and $KL[f(x) || g(x) ]$ is intermediate, violating the bound.

I now see that indeed the inequality doesn't generally hold. Though I don't quite understand why you require $f$ and $g$ to be equal conditional on $a=1$, it seems simpler to do this: Let $f$ and $g$ be similar on subset $X'\subset X$, but $f$ in addition assign high probability to $X_f$ and $g$ assign high probability to $X_g$ (but both assign low non-zero probability to the other.  Then just condition on "x is not in X'$.

I wonder though, if we can still get a bound on $KL[f_a(x) || g_a(x) ]$ by making some kind of assumption that bounds an entropy or KL of $h(a|x)$ somehow.

See if these results help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883279/conditional-kullback-divergence, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016421/confused-by-kullback-leibler-on-conditional-probability-distributions

@user56834, Sure, there are probably many routes to a counterexample.
